# how to run docker container in azure? ManagedEnvironmentNotProvisioned issue

Tags: azure, docker

I need to run simple docker container in azure cloud.
My plan:

1. To upload it to Azure registry - Done
2. To make Azure Container Apps, with container from 1 paragraph - Problem

When I try to create it, I have (ManagedEnvironmentNotProvisioned):

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ManagedEnvironmentNotProvisioned","message":"The environment '/subscriptions/6d0ea58f-8582-45db-8bce-bab8708c8c52/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup-CUS/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/managedEnvironment-DefaultResource-bae6' has not been provisioned successfully."}]}
```

What wrong can I do? What can be wrong with Managed Environment?

Answer (score 0):

What commands did you use? Ideally, you should create ManagedEnvironment firstly, check that it's okay and then create Container App. Smt like that:

```
1. az containerapp env create -n MyContainerappEnvironment -g arm-rg --location westeurope
2. az containerapp env show -n MyContainerappEnvironment -g arm-rg\
3. az containerapp create -n MyApp -g arm-rg --environment MyContainerappEnvironment --image docker.io/nginx/latest --min-replicas 1 --max-replicas 1
```

All az cli commands can be found here: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest)